# algorithm for spacing objects minimally apart

Tags: javascript, algorithm

given a bunch of rectangles of random small sizes (generally 3-8 per side) on a Cartesian plane, with the top left of each of these given as x,y coordinates assigned at random between -1 and 1, how can I spread them out minimally so there is no overlap in a fashion that preserves their relative x,y positioning?

I would love an answer in javascript but any readable code will do

here's some quick and easy javascript to get it going:

```
for(some_number_of_rectangles)
  squares.push({
    x:random(-1,1), 
    y:random:(-1,1), 
    width:random(3,8), 
    height:random(3,8)
  })
```

example output from that:

```
[ 
  {x:0.5,y:0,width:2,height:2}, //intersects 3rd
  {x:0,y:1,width:2,height:2}, // intersects 4th
  {x:-1,y:0,width:2,height:2},
  {x:0,y:-0.5,width:2,height:2}, //intersects 5th
  {x:0,y:-1.5,width:2,height:2}
] // to simplify the problem, the sizes are all the same, but that won't be the case usually
```

and its solution:

```
[ // no intersections now
  {x:1,y:0,width:2,height:2}, // movement: 0.5
  {x:0,y:2,width:2,height:2}, // movement: 1
  {x:-2,y:0,width:2,height:2}, // movement: 1
  {x:0,y:-1,width:2,height:2} // movement: 0.5
  {x:0,y:-3,width:2,height:2} // movement: 1.5
]
```

Comment: You can increase base number passed to `x.random()` by `width:random()` multiplied by two, for padding on either side on x plane

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking: if you preserve their relative x,y positioning, in what manner could you spread them out at all?

Comment: I added example input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
factor = 0
for a in rectangles:
    for b in rectangles:
        factor = max(
            factor,
            min(
                max(
                    a.width / (b.x - a.x),
                    b.width / (a.x - b.x)
                ),
                max(
                    a.height / (b.y - a.y),
                    b.height / (a.y - b.y)
                )
            )
        )
// now multiply all coordinates with factor
```

Reasoning:
Afterwards for every pair of rectangles, either

```
factor >= a.width / (b.x - a.x) and factor >= b.width / (a.x - b.x)
```

or

```
factor >= a.height / (b.y - a.y) and factor >= b.height / (a.y - b.y)
```

Now suppose for example `a.x <= b.x` and `a.y <= b.y`. Then either by the first line

```
factor*b.x >= factor*a.x + a.width
```

or by the second line

```
factor*b.y >= factor*a.y + a.height
```

therefore a and b can not overlap in both x and y, so they don't overlap in 2d.
The other cases handle analogously.

By definition of `factor`, at least one of these inequalities will hold with equality, therefore the resulting factor is the smallest possible solution.